# an error occurred (invalids3objectexception) when calling the startdocumenttextdetection operation: unable to get object metadata

Tags: python

I just want to create a basic Python program to use Textract on a PDF document and display the output. I get this error:
an error occurred (invalids3objectexception) when calling the startdocumenttextdetection operation: unable to get object metadata from s3. check object key, region and/or access permissions.

I have my AWS account setup with a bitbucket. I'm not sure what else I need to do. Any advise is appreciated.

```
import boto3
import time

def startJob(s3BucketName, objectName):
    response = None
    client = boto3.client('textract')
    response = client.start_document_text_detection(
    DocumentLocation={
        'S3Object': {
            'Bucket': s3BucketName,
            'Name': objectName
        }
    })

    return response["JobId"]

def isJobComplete(jobId):
    time.sleep(5)
    client = boto3.client('textract')
    response = client.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId)
    status = response["JobStatus"]
    print("Job status: {}".format(status))

    while(status == "IN_PROGRESS"):
        time.sleep(5)
        response = client.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId)
        status = response["JobStatus"]
        print("Job status: {}".format(status))

    return status

def getJobResults(jobId):

    pages = []

    time.sleep(5)

    client = boto3.client('textract')
    response = client.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId)
    
    pages.append(response)
    print("Resultset page recieved: {}".format(len(pages)))
    nextToken = None
    if('NextToken' in response):
        nextToken = response['NextToken']

    while(nextToken):
        time.sleep(5)

        response = client.get_document_text_detection(JobId=jobId, NextToken=nextToken)

        pages.append(response)
        print("Resultset page recieved: {}".format(len(pages)))
        nextToken = None
        if('NextToken' in response):
            nextToken = response['NextToken']

    return pages

# Document
s3BucketName = "textractpdfbuckect"
documentName = "Amazon-Textract-Pdf.pdf"

jobId = startJob(s3BucketName, documentName)
print("Started job with id: {}".format(jobId))
if(isJobComplete(jobId)):
    response = getJobResults(jobId)

#print(response)

# Print detected text
for resultPage in response:
    for item in resultPage["Blocks"]:
        if item["BlockType"] == "LINE":
            print ('\033[94m' +  item["Text"] + '\033[0m')
```